# How can I decrypt AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding with PBKDF2withHmacSHA1 in PHP with salt?

Tags: php, encryption, aes

thanks so much for reading.

I did so much research on this topic but did not get any further.

I have to decode data in PHP. This is the specification of the encryption (and there is no more specification to get from the encryptor):

keylength = 256
algorithm = AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding
keyspec   = PBKDF2withHmacSHA1
iterations = 5000

What I also got, is a key, 49 characters long for decryption.

Each encrypted message is provided in an Array and it's base64 encoded

Example data:

```
$data = [
    "iv" => "DoJQNS0WZRtWB...",
    "salt" => "zkcHInm4ewweKG81...",
    "encrypted_data" => "30MTuQEW4sVc3...",
];
```

I tried this:

```
$password = "supersecretkey";
$salt     = base64_decode($data['salt']);
$iterations = 5000;

$key_length = 32;
$is_raw_output = true;


$key = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, $iterations, $key_length, true);


$iv = base64_decode($data['iv']);
$encstr = base64_decode($data['encrypted_data']);

$output = openssl_decrypt($encstr, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING, $iv);

var_dump($output);
var_dump(openssl_error_string());
```

what I get here is

```
bool(false)

string(94) "error:0606508A:digital envelope routines:EVP_DecryptFinal_ex:data not multiple of block length"
```

I'm not sure if this is the correct approach. I tried also decoding directly without using the hash_pbkdf2 function but all I receive then is garbage.

So if I just use this

```
$key = "supersecretkey";
$iv = base64_decode($data['iv']);
$encstr = base64_decode($data['encrypted_data']);
$output = openssl_decrypt($encstr, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_ZERO_PADDING| OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);
```

then I just get garbage data like

```
*+�l��_�y9�{(kNF7��gص��[Se!Y
```

I would appreciate any help on this topic as I already spent a lot of hours and read tons of documentation.

Unfortunately I do not get any more support from the entity that sends the encrypted data.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45567962/convert-encrypt-and-decrypt-c-sharp-function-to-php-function/45574121#45574121 something like that ?

Comment: Only `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA` may be set as `$options` (4th parameter) because 1. the ciphertext is explicitly Base64 decoded and 2. according to the description PKCS#7 (or PKCS#5) padding is used. Presumably (with respect to your test) this choice results in a decryption error or empty output, which is caused by inconsistent data and/or a wrong specification of the algorithm parameters. For an analysis either the encryption code is needed or a *complete* set of test data: password, salt, IV, plaintext and ciphertext.

Comment: Thanks for your answers. If I use the answer of FatFreddy, where to place the "salt"? And Topaco, do you think I need ```hash_pbkdf2```, is this the right approach? They do not provide the encryption code and I cannot post the real data for Privacy reasons. The encryptor is not very supportive and says the provided information is enough for decryption

Comment: *PBKDF2withHmacSHA1* corresponds to `hash_pbkdf2()` with `'sha1'` as 1st parameter, i.e. this is fine. Apart from the `$options` (i.e. the 4th) parameter, which should be `OPENSSL_RAW_DATA`, I can't see any error in the code, see also [here](https://paiza.io/projects/UDOtWszBlCm7zYzGwHjK4w), so the possibility of inconsistent data and/or algorithm description should also be considered. Btw, the linked code from the comment uses SHA256 as key derivation and no PBKDF2, which does not fit to the algorithm description.

Answer (score 0):

Hi thanks all for helping me out.

The correct solution to this problem is below.

Obviously we were sent an incorrect encryption key. They generated a new one - but they insisted that the old one was correct - and then it worked like charm!

Thanks again.

```
$salt     = base64_decode($datasend['salt']);
$iterations = 5000;

$key_length = 32;

$key = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $e2ekey, $salt, $iterations, $key_length, true);

$iv = base64_decode($datasend['iv']);
$encstr = base64_decode($datasend['encryptedMessage']);

$datasend = openssl_decrypt($encstr, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, OPENSSL_RAW_DATA, $iv);

$datasend = json_decode($datasend,true);
```